# mount_root not working/ found linux openwrt

Tags: linux, openwrt

I've updated my openwrt firmware using the web interface. Now the web interface is unreachable.

I lost my root password so i started my router (wr1043nd) in failsafe mode, but the mount_root command is not working:
$mount_root
""/bin/ash: mount_root: not found""

Any clue? I can't find any solution in the docs/ online

Answer (score -1):

You can mount jffs2 partition manually. This partition contains your configuration, so when you mount it, you will be able to edit root password.

Use this command: `mount -t jffs2 /dev/mtdblock3 /mnt/`. Please note that mtd number may vary in different routers. If there is nothing in /mnt dir after issuing this command, try another mtdblock number.

Then go to `/mnt` dir and remove `etc/shadow` and `etc/passwd` files from there to reset root password.

Comment: Removing `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/passwd` effectively bricks your router and you'll end up with bootloop. Don't do this!

Comment: @DenisTheMenace Deleting them from the jffs2 partition should work fine for resetting the password I think. The system will just read the original files from the normal partition.